# Puppetter и WebSocket

Tags: node.js, websocket, puppeteer

**Проблема:** Я скраплю страницу при помощи Puppetter на которой есть несколько Websocket соединений. И одно из соединений представляет собой видеострим который сильно тормозит работу (я запускаю через google cloud function + использую прокси = для меня очень важен вопрос минимизации трафика, ресурсов и скорость выполнения).

**Задача:** Заблокировать одно из соединений.

**Варианты решения:**

- Запретить доступ к этому URL
- Оборвать соединение после подключения
- Обернуть нативный WebSocket

**Что я попытался сделать**

*Запретить доступ к этому URL.* К сожалению, через `page.on('request', () => {})` не видно этих запросов. Об этом есть вот такая ветка https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2974

Запуская вот так, получаешь все соединения кроме WebSocket

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', async (request) => {
    console.log(request.url());
})
```

*Оборвать соединение после подключения.* Здесь я вообще не нашел никаких решений. Я понимаю как при помощи `CDPSession` получить инфу о WS подключениях, скрапить данные оттуда, но вот если и можно как-то отрубить соединение - я незнаю как.

```
const session = await page.target().createCDPSession();

const subscribe = async (session: CDPSession) => {
  session.on('sessionattached', (s) => {
    subscribe(s);
  });

  session.send('Network.enable');

  session.on('Network.webSocketCreated', (payload) => {
    console.log('webSocketCreated', payload.url)
  })

  session.send('Runtime.runIfWaitingForDebugger');
}

await session.send('Target.setAutoAttach', {
  autoAttach: true,
  flatten: true,
  waitForDebuggerOnStart: true,
});

subscribe(session);
```

**Что я делать не хочу**

*Оборачивать нативный WS* и самому решать что там делать с подключениями. Я понимаю как это реализовать, но мне очень не хочется идти по этому пути

Буду признателен за любую подсказку!

**UPD**
Страница спрятана за авторизацию, не публичную. Так что дать адрес не могу. Потестировать свое решение можно например вот здесь
https://piehost.com/websocket-tester
Подключившись к этому Websocket серверу wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/etheur@trade

Comment: а можете написать адрес страницы, которую вы загружаете?

Comment: @nörbörnën апдейтнул пост

Comment: Если честно не совсем представляю необходимость останавливать сокет, когда можно остановить код(ошибкой) если конечно это не противоречит скрапингу

Comment: Патчи вебсокет из самого puppeter'а.

Comment: @Daniil Loban Код останавливать нельзя, там сильно нагруженная страница с кучей JS'а. Там вся задача, соскрапить некоторые вызовы которые делает JS.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно чуть расширить ваш ответ, я не совсем понял.

Comment: @АлександрРогонов, делаешь что-то типа executeScript, в котором monkey-патчишь вебсокет так, чтобы он делал то, что ты хочешь.